# Text Entered in search textfield not passing in parameters

Tags: plugins, shopware

Thank you in advance,

I have my own custom backend plugin where there is a listing of employees, I also put search field to search the employee, when I type in the search text field, it is executing the link like

http://localhost/shopware_demo/backend/employee_plugin/reloadAssociation?_dc=111111111&id=1&association=employees&page=1&start=0&limit=20, but it is not appending parameters of text inputted in the search text field, I checked the core plugin where I am able to see the parameters for search text like

```
_dc: 11111111
page: 1
start: 0
limit: 20
sort: [{"property":"id","direction":"DESC"}]
filter: [{"property":"search","value":"new","operator":null,"expression":null}])
```

but in my case, there is like

```
_dc: 22222222
page: 1
start: 0
limit: 20
sort: [{"property":"id","direction":"DESC"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to define `remoteFilter: true` in your `EmployeeStore`: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-remoteFilter